# How to deal with a memory-leaking fork bomb on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, freeze, memory-leaks, forking

I know that a fork bomb can be prevented by limiting the number of processes of a single user, and memory leaking will not freeze my OS for Linux has OOM killer. But how about a memory-leaking fork bomb?

```
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> vec;
    do {
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++)
                vec.push_back(rand());
        } catch (bad_alloc e) {
        }
        fork();
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

My Linux got frozen after tried this code. Is there anyway I can prevent it from freezing?
The code is tested on Archlinux, Linux 4.0.5

compile the code just using this command:
`g++ -o test test.cpp`

More information: As the code can eat up all my memory by just forking a few times, it is not like a normal fork bomb, and limiting the number of processes is useless. Also, fork() is executed frequently (when there's low memory) so that OOM-killer is much slower than forks.
As a result, I have to use Alt-SysRq-R-E-I to stop these processes, but that's not what I want.

This is my first time to ask on SuperUser. Help me if my question is inappropriate. And thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you trying to prevent rapid memory depletion? Why would this ever happen with a regular program? (Unless this is a corporate environment and you want to super-harden your workstations.)

Comment: @oldmud0 I believe it should not happen with normal programs. However, firefox have dirven my system to freeze several times, maybe by memory leak(I think). But a normal memory-leaking program is always stopped by OOM-killer. So I just started to find the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be a memory leaking fork bomb - even, for example, a `make -j` (or with a too high `j` factor) on a moderate code size or any process spawning a pile of descendents (fewer than the reasonable limit for an active user), each chewing an amount of memory significant by itself but too small to be targeted by the OOM killer (or to offer a significant relief when nailed by the OOM killer) can have have a similar effect.

It's possible to write a customized monitoring script/tool (to be executed by root at high priority) which could watch for such process spawning patterns and, if necessary, kill them by pgid or userid (i.e simultaneouly, not one by one like the OOM killer) before they become fatal to the system. Would work for *reasonable* spawning/resource draining rates, but I'm not sure if possible for just *any* rates.

Comment: So the kernel cannot prevent it, right? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Not via a method that I know of.

Comment: Actually, can't cgroups of the kernel place limits on resources like memory that would be respected here?  To monitor and then try to catch it is sort of a race condition, but I think predetermined limits are much more easily enforceable.

Comment: @ttbek with predetermined limits it's difficult to strike a decent balance between underutilizing the system when few users/processes are active and overloading the system when many such users/processes are active. On a 32 core system I'd like the equivalent of `-j32` if one user builds and `-j8` if 4 users are building. Either value is OK in one case, but not so in the other.

Comment: @DanCornilescu You can do that.  CPU shares (not quota) can be assigned to the users as 250 each.  Unused shares are available for anyone, so one user building can use all CPU cycles available, but when 4 are running they will each get a 1/4 of the cycles.  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sect-cpu-Example_Usage.html  By predetermined I meant something like the above, the kernel is able to pull cpu cycles away from user one even if his process started first.

Comment: In some other areas it is common to use a harder limit, for instance, it is common when formating HDs for as much as 5% to be reserved for root/system.  Reserving a few hundred MB of RAM for root with the cgroups (or cgroups2) memory controller may (or may not, I'm not sure of this) help against the proposed scenario.  It should trigger the OOM, whenever the boundary is crossed, though you can also have it trigger custom functions instead if I recall. May still be a race, but I guess if the kernel can't win the race you're out of luck with anything else.